# How to implement a digital signature for 21 CFR Part 11 for non repudiation

Tags: digital-signature, non-repudiation

I would like to know what is the best way to implement a digital signature to achive [Non-Repudation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation) to acomplish [21-CFR-Part11-SubpartC-11.100.part-c](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/CFRSearch.cfm?CFRPart=11&showFR=1&subpartNode=21:1.0.1.1.8.3). Anybody has implemented this for 21 CFR 11?

Non repudiation means that if a users sign the document. For him is impossible to say that he didn't sign that document. It should be equivalent to handwritten signature. [see-here-for-more-info](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/how-to-achieve-non-repudiation/6108#6108?newreg=efd4ce83c92b49b2bc1613b77e286014)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the problem is more of a legal than technical/implementation issue. Your links above to the FDA regulations and the other stackoverflow question [How to achieve non-repudiation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1786/72057) emphasizes the legal aspect of it as well.

That means you will need to ensure compliance to laws of each country (e.g. [ESIGN Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Signatures_in_Global_and_National_Commerce_Act) in the US). What is interesting about ESIGN is that it preserves the right of a person to NOT use electronic signatures. Might I suggest using a service such as https://www.docusign.com/ instead - see its section on [legality](https://www.docusign.com/how-it-works/legality).