# 2fa attestation object for non-repudiation

Tags: yubikey, non-repudiation, webauthn

I am reading on digital signatures:

> A valid digital signature gives a recipient reason to believe that the
>   message was created by a known sender (authentication), that the
>   sender cannot deny having sent the message (**nonrepudiation),** and that
>   the message was not altered in transit (integrity).

I'm using for 2FA a hardware key (e.g. Yubikey, Key-id) to authenticate a user with [Webauthn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API) and also later require user's confirmation to take certain sensitive actions.

*Question:* if I store on the server the challenge and the AuthenticatorAttestationObject returned by the hardware key, can that serve for non-repudiation?

*Rephrase:* can the user claim that an action that required pressing the Yubikey button was not initiated by him, but was fabricated e.g. from server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-repudiation is [much harder](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6108) to achieve than some would have you believe. In general, a signature is tied to a key with a very high degree of confidence, but tying the key to a specific person and their intent is much harder. With WebAuthn though, you can't achieve any of this.

A signature is over specific data. For your goal you'd want that data to be something along the lines of "I [user] consent to the server performing [sensitive action] at time [time]". What you're actually getting though is something like "I am definitely the user known by [website] as [user]". Not terribly helpful, because as you pointed out, the user could just claim that the server performed a different action at a different time than the one he intended to authorize.

Even if you were able to solve that problem though, and you could get a signature for a statement authorizing a certain action at a certain time, the signature isn't really coming from the user, it's coming from software using the key. Problem is, the software is *your* software; they could just claim the JavaScript sent to them was modified to create a signature without their consent.

And of course, there's always the possibility of claiming "my key was stolen" or "that's not my key, it's a key that was fabricated by the server". In the end, it's really up to who a jury (or whomever you're trying to prove this to) believes is trustworthy.

Comment: The link you posted on the first line was most useful. Many thanks. Indeed a thorny problem.